# Dialogflow - Entity with different reference values and similar synonyms

Tags: machine-learning, chatbot, dialogflow-es

Help me to resolve the query for Dialogflow agent!

I've defined an entity called "ProgrammingLanguages" and assigned 2 different reference values with common synonyms like below :

```
Android  -  Mobile OS, Mobile Development, Google
iOS      -  Mobile OS, Mobile Development, Apple
```

Already defined a intent with parameter named "ProgrammingLanguages" along with isList selected "Yes"

Now when I ask my agent "Show me the list of mobile os", it always returns "Android" only! when I replaced the sequence for values inside entity, it started showing me "iOS", That means, it's always taking the first value and didn't show all the values with similar synonyms for that particular entity!

Could someone help me to understand this behaviour?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work correctly. You cannot put same synonyms for different Entity values. If you are using the same synonyms that means the two entities are same.

isList is used to capture multiple values for a parameter like if I am collecting brand names of cars, my entity will be car_brands and user can provide single value or multiple like Ferrari, Benz, Bugati, BMW or only Suzuki.

If you ask your agent "Show the list of mobile os" that means, it should return Android and iOS. Entities are not used to return response values. They are used to capture category for which you want bot/agent to return value.

In your case,

- create an Entity and put all the above synonyms under one say "mobileOS".
- when the user uses synonyms, mobileOS will be the captured parameter.
- use it to decide and return all the mobile OS.

You don't need to enable isList as you are not collecting a list of values from the user.

Comment: 1st thing is I didn't create two different entities, I've created single entity called "ProgrammingLanguages" inside this entity I could add number of reference values right? where each value will have number of synonyms, and logically Isn't it correct?

Comment: That is correct. But, Each value should be different from each other. Like if I create  a Gender Entity, I will put male and female as two values and they will have their synonyms. This way the parameter value I will get will be either male or female. From your question, it looks you want both and that too as a response to the user. These entities are used by the bot/agent to to identify what the user is asking and not what it should send to the user.